# Python: Distributing a file/module into another package with setuptools

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

Generically, I'm trying to distribute a module/file that I want to be part of a another python package that has already set up a directory structure under site-packages.

For the given structure under site-packages:

```
-- main_package
   -- __init__.py
   -- sub_package
      -- __init__.py
      -- bar.py
```

I have a module `foo.py` that I want to exist next to the module `bar.py`, both under the package `sub_package`. If I just setup the structure in my repo along the lines of a typical package then the `__init__.py` that setuptools requires clobber the existing `__init__.py` files for the `main_package` and `sub_package`. Ideally this would be a wheel or sdist that could be distributed from our own pypi.

I've tried using `py_module`, but I can't get it to place the module anywhere other than the top level under site-packages.

Specifically, I'm trying to distribute a saltstack external_pillar into the salt/pillar/ structure already setup by salt. There are multiple salt instances that may or may not want the external_pillar, so simply bundling up the pillar into the salt distribution we have isn't feasible.

Comment: Why do you want to install this module under an existing site-packages directory? What behaviour do you expect?

Comment: I expect that `import main_package.sub_package.foo` will work

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for [namespace packages](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/).

With in your case a structure like this:

```
`-- main_package
   |  # no __init__.py here
   `-- sub_package
      |-- __init__.py
      `-- foo.py
```

> Python 3.3 added implicit namespace packages from PEP 420. All that is required to create a native namespace package is that you just omit `__init__.py` from the namespace package directory.
>
> ...
>
> It is extremely important that every distribution that uses the namespace package omits the `__init__.py` or uses a pkgutil-style `__init__.py`. If any distribution does not, it will cause the namespace logic to fail and the other sub-packages will not be importable.
>
> ...
>
> Finally, every distribution must provide the `namespace_packages` argument to `setup()` in setup.py.

However, from your question I am not sure whether `sub_package` already exists in `main_package` or not.

If it does, I am not sure of the structure to use to extend `sub_package` while not shadowing its modules, you may need to use an alternate sub-package name to achieve this.

Comment: "For the given structure under site-packages:" implies that `sub_packages` already exists. This solution doesn't work as the `__init__.py` for `sub_package` in your example will still overwrite the `__init__.py` in the given `sub_package` directory.

Comment: @Silfheed, then you could fork the package of interest and add your files. Or create a namespace package with the original subpackage, __init__ and modules, plus your own. But it may be clearer for users to allow discrimination between the original one and yours in some way, so a slightly different name could be a good thing.